# Away3D 4.x alter ProjectionCenter

Tags: actionscript-3, projection, away3d

How to alter the projection center in Away3D using a `perspectiveLens`.

I know it can be done with the standard flash 3d library, using:

```
root.transform.perspectiveProjection.projectionCenter = new Point(center.x, center.y);
```

But no such function exists when looking into the Away3D classes.
Does away3D achieve this by using another method?

Answer (score 0):

Object3d or anything that descends from it does have 'pivotPoint'.

But usually you'll just want to move your camera around.

```
camera.z = -1000;
camera.x = 500;
camera.y = 500;

// after moving the camera you'll want to re-orient towards your scene.
//for instance to look at the origin:
camera.lookAt( new Vector3D(0,0,0));
```

edit:
If you're just trying to rotate an object try pan() pitch() and roll().